# How do you programmatically configure the Serial FIFO Receive and Transmit Buffers in Windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port, buffer, fifo, labview

From Device Manager in Windows it is possible to configure the Receive Buffer and Transmit FIFO Buffer sizes for a serial port from Advanced Settings for a COM port:

[image: Windows Device MAnager FIFO Configuration]

I would like to configure the values for the TX and RX FIFO buffers for COM ports programmatically. Ideally a method to do it in LabVIEW or even via .NET / command line as both are easy to interface with from LabVIEW.

Edit: Just to clarify this is in regards to the 16550 compatible UART FIFO buffers and not software buffers like the [VISA I/O Buffer](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/98F799364B833C2A86256ADC00732073), etc.

Answer (score 1):

A few options are available that are not as ideal for this case but useful to note:

The CodeProject post by Vladimir titled ["Serial Ports. Enumeration and FIFO control"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4187/Serial-ports-Enumeration-and-FIFO-control?msg=751516#xx751516xx) has an approach that uses the Microsoft Driver Development Kit (DDK) which is now the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) in Visual C++.

The forum ["How to set Serial port Fifo buffers without reboot"](http://www.winvistatips.com/set-serial-port-fifo-buffers-without-reboot-t176870.html) describes that the values can be changed in the registry (manually or programmatically I suppose) and then the serial port interface restarted using the [DEVCON command-line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ddk_example_38_restart_a_device_tools). I am not sure how reliable that approach and documentation is hard to find.